# for loop crashing after first iteration

Tags: c++, for-loop, crash, structure

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct person
{
    string name;
    int numberofpies;
    string flavour;
};

int main ()
{
    for (int i=1; i<10; i++)
    {
    cout << "press <1> to add a person or press <2> to get results" << endl;
    int input;
    cin >> input;
    person newperson[i];
    string names, flavours;
    int numbersofpies;
    if (input==1)
      {
        cout << "please enter your name " << endl;
        cin >> names;
        cout << "enter the number of pies you ate" << endl;
        cin >> numbersofpies;
        cout << "enter the flavour" << endl;
        cin >> flavours;
        newperson[i].numberofpies=numbersofpies;
        newperson[i].flavour=flavours;
        newperson[i].name=names;
      }
      else if(input == 2)
      {
          int x=1;
          while (x>i)
          {
              cout << "name : " << newperson[x].name << endl;
              cout << "number of pies : " << newperson[x].numberofpies<< endl;
              cout << "flavour: " << newperson[x].flavour << endl;

          }goto point;
      }


    }point:
        return 0;    
}
```

My problem is that this code compiles normally and runs perfectly until the first loop ends and then it crashes so after experimenting and trying different solutions i realized that the problem is in the last three lines of the 'if statement'

```
newperson[i].numberofpies=numbersofpies;
newperson[i].flavour=flavours;
newperson[i].name=names;
```

since after removing them the problem goes away. However, the program would obviously not do what its supposed to do, so I guess my question whats wrong in these lines and if they're not the problem what is? and how do I fix it?
Also I don't mind alternative approaches at all if it has ideas that I can learn from but I'm most importantly interested in understanding the problem to learn not get the program running?

Comment: Review the chapter of your book about arrays again.

Comment: seriously that's all you have to say you couldn't tell me my mistake ?

Comment: Check array index bounds limits. Also, variable length arrays are not standard c++ but an extension offered by some compiler that it's best to avoid.

Comment: @fahad97azawi Seeing the way you posted your question here without showing any debugging efforts, I actually consider such is a good advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`person newperson[i];` is declaring a **variable length array**, and VLAs are a non-standard vendor-specific compiler extension. Don't use them. If you need a variable length array, use `std::vector` instead.

In this case, your code has **undefined behavior**, because your loop variable `i` is always out of bounds of the VLA you are allocating, so when you try to set members of the array, `newperson[i]` is reaching into surrounding memory outside the array. That is why your code crashes.

Array indexes are 0-based, but your loop variable is 1-based. So, on the first iteration, you are allocating an array with 1 element in it, but then accessing the second element. On the second iteration, you are allocating an array with 2 elements in it, but then accessing the third element. And so on

Answer (score 2):

When you declare your arrays like this

```
person newperson[i];
```

it makes a new array of size `i`, meaning that indexes from 0, inclusive, to `i-1`, inclusive, are allowed on `newperson` array. This is a problem, because indexing `newperson[i]` is illegal.

In addition, `newperson`'s size is not known until runtime, meaning that it is a variable-length array; C++ standard does not allow this, so you are using a popular extension.

Fixing the issue is straightforward - move the declaration outside the loop, and make it

```
person newperson[10];
```

You need to fix a few other issues with this code:

- both `i` in the `for` loop and `x` in the `while` loop needs to start at zero, not one.
- `goto` should be avoided; in this situation, a `break` is sufficient.
- When `i` reaches ten, no output is possible. This may be fine, but you may want to force *some* output to alert end-user of this condition. For example, entering `2` could exit the loop, and the `while` loop could be right after the `for` loop. This would gracefully deal with the `goto`/`break` issue, and there would be no duplicate code.

Comment: And make your loop start from 0 rather than 1.

Comment: @pie3636 Yeah, OP seems to have missed that part in two places (`i` and `x`).

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the first iteration:

`i=1`, so the definion:

```
    person newperson[i];
```

define an array of length 1.

now, when you assign:

```
            newperson[i].numberofpies=numbersofpies;
```

you access to the second item of the array (since `newperson[0]` is the first item and `newperson[1]` is the seconed), which didn't exist.

What you realy want to do is to define:

```
person newperson[10];
```

**outside** the loop, and iterate from `i=0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct person
{
    string name;
    int numberofpies;
    string flavour;
};

int main ()
{
const int Pcount = 10;
int input;
cin >> input;
person newperson[Pcount];
string names, flavours;
int numbersofpies;

for (int i=1; i<Pcount; i++)
    {
    cout << "press <1> to add a person or press <2> to get results" << endl;
        if (input==1)
      {
        cout << "please enter your name " << endl;
        cin >> names;
        cout << "enter the number of pies you ate" << endl;
        cin >> numbersofpies;
        cout << "enter the flavour" << endl;
        cin >> flavours;
        newperson[i].numberofpies=numbersofpies;
        newperson[i].flavour=flavours;
        newperson[i].name=names;
      }
      else if(input == 2)
      {
          int x=1;
          while (x>i)
          {
              cout << "name : " << newperson[x].name << endl;
              cout << "number of pies : " << newperson[x].numberofpies<< endl;
              cout << "flavour: " << newperson[x].flavour << endl;

          }
          break;
      }


    }
        return 0;    
}
```

Try to do it like this way at least.

Answer (score 0):

1. Take `person newperson[i];` outside of the for loop and change it to `person newperson[10];`
2. Change `while (x>i)` to `while (x<=i)`
3. Add `x++;` before the close of the while loop.

Here is the edited code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct person
{
    string name;
    int numberofpies;
    string flavour;
};

int main ()
{
    person newperson[10];
    for (int i=1; i<10; i++)
    {
    cout << "press <1> to add a person or press <2> to get results" << endl;
    int input;
    cin >> input;
    string names, flavours;
    int numbersofpies;
    if (input==1)
      {
        cout << "please enter your name " << endl;
        cin >> names;
        cout << "enter the number of pies you ate" << endl;
        cin >> numbersofpies;
        cout << "enter the flavour" << endl;
        cin >> flavours;
        newperson[i].numberofpies=numbersofpies;
        newperson[i].flavour=flavours;
        newperson[i].name=names;
      }
      else if(input == 2)
      {
          int x=1;
          while (x<=i)
          {
              cout << "name : " << newperson[x].name << endl;
              cout << "number of pies : " << newperson[x].numberofpies<< endl;
              cout << "flavour: " << newperson[x].flavour << endl;
              x++;
          }goto point;
      }


    }point:
        return 0;    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you are incorrectly allocating memory for a person array
let's declare a constant holding the number of elements to be stored in the array

```
const int NUM_PERSON =10;
```

or

```
#define NUM_PERSON 10;
```

add this before entering the loop
what this does is allocate enough memory for 10 objects of type person

```
person newperson[NUM_PERSON]
```

now you can access it's elements by using syntax

```
newperson[i].numberofpies
newperson[i].flavour
newperson[i].name
```

Comment: Doesn't help, regarding the _off by one bug_.